# How can I create a Powershell script that can leverage the standard confirm switch?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have a .ps1 with this content (the actual content does not matter) :

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $someArgument
)

# Do something risky
Remove-Item "c:\path\$someArgument.txt"
```

I'd like to add to my script (or to any method in fact) a confirmation message, that can be switch off (on by default).

```
.\myscript.ps1 "foo" -Confirm:$false
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Advanced functions, you can use something called ShouldProcess.

At the top of your script, you can add an attribute called [CmdletBinding]

```
[CmdletBinding(

        SupportsShouldProcess=$true,

        ConfirmImpact="High"

    )]
```

Once you have that, in the body of your function, you need to use an if statement

```
if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($thingIamGoingToChange))
```

Take a look at help about_advanced_functions and help about_functions_cmdletbinding.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to dive into the possibilities of CmdLetBinding... guessing I can go far further with it :)